# Batch. Parameters inside strings?

Tags: string, batch-file, parameters

So this is the first question i am asking here so go easy on me.

```
set /p num= 
for /l %%a in (1,1,%num%) do set /p line%%a= 
for /l %%b in (1,1,%num%) do (echo %line%%b%)>>file.txt
```

The problem is that i try to have a parameter inside a string, so what other way is it to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
set /p num= 
for /l %%a in (1,1,%num%) do set /p line%%a=
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion 
for /l %%b in (1,1,%num%) do (echo !line%%b!)>>file.txt
```

this ?

Answer (score 0):

[EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

> Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution
>   time rather than at parse time, this option is turned on with the
>   `SETLOCAL` command. When delayed expansion is in effect variables may
>   be referenced using `!variable_name!` (in addition to the normal
>   `%variable_name%`)

```
set "num=2"
set /p "num=enter number (%num%) "  
for /l %%a in (1,1,%num%) do set /p "line%%a=line%%a "  
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
(for /l %%b in (1,1,%num%) do echo !line%%b!)>>file.txt 
ENDLOCAL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%b in (1,1,%num%) do echo !line%%b!>>file.txt
```

Or if you don't want to use delayed expansion:

```
for /l %%b in (1,1,%num%) do echo %%line%%b%%>>file.txt
```